# Sending EMail via Mandrill using HTML form

Tags: html, forms, html-email, mandrill

I have a HTML form which will send emails to a particular email Id using Mandrill. Can anyone help me with t eh step by step code.
I have the SMTP username and SMTP Password. 
Could anyone help me ith the code.

Comment: ho cani send emails using html form , javascript and mandrill